# Calculate NDVI values from images extracted by dates from a list

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

Please find attached basic architecture for my data-extraction procedure of NDVI values per pixel, for all images taken in a certain ROI in given dates:
[image: Data extraction architecture]

The code below represent the architecture on a small scale of date-range and applied only for SEN2 images (to be done later - the same for SEN3 images):

```
//Dates of Interest
var start = ee.Date("2018-04-01");
var finish = ee.Date("2018-05-01");

///--------------------- SENTINEL2 Collection ---------------------------------------///
var sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterDate(start, finish)
.filterBounds(region)
.map(function(image){
  return image
  .clipToCollection(region)
  .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
})

///--------------------- Unique list creation ---------------------------------------///
sen2 = sen2.map(function(image){
  return image.set('simpleDateMillis', ee.Date(image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')).millis())
});
var listMillisSimple = ee.List(sen2.aggregate_array('simpleDateMillis'));
var uniqueDatesSimple = listMillisSimple.distinct();
var SEN2_day0 = uniqueDatesSimple.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date);
});

print("SEN2 day0:",SEN2_day0);

//------------------------------ AOI ------------------------------//

//define all AOI
var field1 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000000"));


//-----------------------NDVI CALC-----------------------//

//Get the ndvi for the specific field and time
function get_ndvi_sen2(subRegion, image) {
  var ndvi_s2 = image
     .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
     .rename('ndvi_s2');

  var ndvi_s2_Features = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ndvi_s2
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: subRegion,
    scale: 10
  })
  .get('ndvi_s2'))
  .map(function (ndvi_s2) {
    return ee.Feature(null, {ndvi_s2: ndvi_s2});
  })
  );
  return ndvi_s2_Features;
}


//------------------ CSV Export ---------------------//
var sen2_disc, sen2_selc = 'ndvi_s2';
var sen2_folder = 'GOOD/SEN2'

function write_to_drive(col, disc, selc, folder, field){
  print("Col: ",col, "Disc: ",disc, "Selc: ",selc, "Folder: ",folder, "Field: ",field, date);
  Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: col,
  fileNamePrefix: disc+' '+field,
  selectors: [selc],
  folder: folder+'/'+field
  })
}

var feat_per_img = function(sngl_img){
  return get_ndvi_sen2(field1, sngl_img)
}

function write_to_drive_front(feat){
  write_to_drive(feat, 'NDVI_Sen2', sen2_selc, sen2_folder, 'field1');
}

//------ test run for SEN2_day0 list -----//
var allImagesInRange = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.inList("system:time_start", SEN2_day0))


write_to_drive_front(ee.FeatureCollection(allImagesInRange.map(feat_per_img)));
```

I hope it is not too messy.
As of now - the problem is that I get empty feature collection that needs to be later passed to the function that writes it to CSV file. So I get an empty CSV file.

**My main question is - why doesn't the FeatureCollection pass on properly so the Export.table.toDrive could write it to CSV?**

**Another question is why isn't the code extracting as many CSV files as the number of dates on the list?**
 I have mapped the image collection so the procedure of calculating and extracting ndvi values should be on every image of the ImageCollection.

Any ideas?

Comment: You really should try to simplify your code as much as possible. At the very least, remove chunks of unused code. Then ask a single, focused, question. I'm having trouble following your date filtering logic - what you're trying to do there. But I'm guessing you're having problems with that.

Comment: Hello Daniel and thank you for your replay. I get what you are saying and will edit my question so it will be more focused, thank you for the feedback. Regarding date filtering - I will be more specific in my edited question.

Comment: Do you want to export a CSV per date, each containing pixels from all your regions, or do you want a CSV per date and region? Can you, in words, describe which dates you want to include? Is that dates you have imagery for?

Comment: Why do you want to save the values as a csv and not as tif? So, what do you want to do with those csv's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SEN2_day0` contain `ee.Date` objects stripped of time, which you use as a filter for `system:time_start`, which are timestamp contain the time of day. So, both an issue about the type of values, and the time component. One option would be to have `simpleDateMillis` be `ee.Date`, have `SEN2_day0` just be the `uniqueDatesSimple`, and filter on `simpleDateMillis`, instead of `system:time_start`.

```
var region = ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(Map.getBounds(true))])

//Dates of Interest
var start = ee.Date("2018-04-01");
var finish = ee.Date("2018-05-01");

///--------------------- SENTINEL2 Collection ---------------------------------------///
var sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterDate(start, finish)
.filterBounds(region)
.map(function(image){
  return image
  .clipToCollection(region)
  .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
})

///--------------------- Unique list creation ---------------------------------------///
sen2 = sen2.map(function(image){
  return image.set('simpleDateMillis', ee.Date(ee.Date(image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd'))))
});
print(sen2.first().get('simpleDateMillis'))
var listMillisSimple = ee.List(sen2.aggregate_array('simpleDateMillis'));
var uniqueDatesSimple = listMillisSimple.distinct();
var SEN2_day0 = uniqueDatesSimple
print("SEN2 day0:",SEN2_day0);

//------------------------------ AOI ------------------------------//

//define all AOI
var field1 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000000"));


//-----------------------NDVI CALC-----------------------//

//Get the ndvi for the specific field and time
function get_ndvi_sen2(subRegion, image) {
  var ndvi_s2 = image
     .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
     .rename('ndvi_s2');

  var ndvi_s2_Features = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ndvi_s2
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: subRegion,
    scale: 10
  })
  .get('ndvi_s2'))
  .map(function (ndvi_s2) {
    return ee.Feature(null, {ndvi_s2: ndvi_s2});
  })
  );
  return ndvi_s2_Features;
}


//------------------ CSV Export ---------------------//
var sen2_disc, sen2_selc = 'ndvi_s2';
var sen2_folder = 'GOOD/SEN2'

function write_to_drive(col, disc, selc, folder, field){
  print("Col: ",col, "Disc: ",disc, "Selc: ",selc, "Folder: ",folder, "Field: ",field);
  Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: col,
  fileNamePrefix: disc+' '+field,
  selectors: [selc],
  folder: folder+'/'+field
  })
}

var feat_per_img = function(sngl_img){
  return get_ndvi_sen2(field1, sngl_img)
}

function write_to_drive_front(feat){
  write_to_drive(feat, 'NDVI_Sen2', sen2_selc, sen2_folder, 'field1');
}

//------ test run for SEN2_day0 list -----//
var allImagesInRange = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.inList("simpleDateMillis", SEN2_day0))


write_to_drive_front(ee.FeatureCollection(allImagesInRange.map(feat_per_img)));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/499f1b25a3d77ffd2eaa16106b94ecb6

On the question on why you only get a single CSV file exported: You only call `Export.table.toDrive()` once. That will generate a single CSV file.

Comment: Thank you again Daniel. I don't know if it is only on my computer but the CSV comes out empty. Only the header 'ndvi_s2'. Any idea why?